# Why doesn't synchronization work with Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, synchronization, spring-orm

I'm trying to do so simple thing - just to atomically call two calls to database.

I have a Queue (table) in database. One column is "loaded". I have a Spring MVC (with spring boot) application which uses Spring JPA with Hibernate.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/queue/next",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getNext() {
    List<String> pair = queueService.getNext();

    if (pair != null) {
        log.warn("!!! SQL !!! Next {} -> {}", pair.get(0), pair.get(1));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            pair,
            HttpStatus.OK
        );
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

My Service (QueueService):

```
private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

public List<String> getNext() {
    QueueDTO queue;

    log.warn("!!! SQL !!! {}", System.identityHashCode(lock));

    lock.lock();
    try {
        queue = updateQueueService.findNextAvailable();
        if (queue == null) return null;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(2);
    result.add(queue.getStationFromName());
    result.add(queue.getStationToName());
    return result;
}
```

And last service which is working with repository (UpdateQueueService)

```
public synchronized QueueDTO findNextAvailable() {
    entityManager.clear();

    Queue queue = updateQueueRepository.findNextAvailable();

    if (queue == null) return null;

    queue.setLoaded(true);
    updateQueueRepository.save(queue);

    return updateQueueMapper.updateQueueToUpdateQueueDTO(queue);
}
```

In my code you could see that I've used everything to synchronize reading from queue and updating:

1. I've used ReentrantLock
2. I've used synchronized on the service's method
3. I've cleared associated EntityManager

But I could see by logs that method is returning duplicated items from queue when more than 100 users starting to call it fastly.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Just thinking that the problem somewhere in using of JPA here.

Comment: Atomicity and isolation are provided by database transactions, not by JVM locks. A database transaction, in the typical default READ_COMMITTED isolation level, doesn't see any change that is not committed yet by another transaction. Moreover, you seem to think that save() writes the queue to the database. It doesn't. save() is completely useless here. The update is done by JPA at flush time (most probably, here, just before committing the transaction). You need to rethink about your logic in terms of database transactions, and optimistic or pessimistic database locks.

Comment: @JBNizet Am I right that if my service classes marked by `@Transactional` that method `UpdateQueueService.findNextAvailable()` will make everything in one transaction. And I need to mark my repository method `updateQueueRepository.findNextAvailable()` by `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`?